# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@hapi/hawk'

Tags: angular, authentication

I try to use `hawk` for absence.io in an `angular 11` app.

```
npm i hawk (9.0.0)
npm i @types/hapi__hawk (8.0.1)
```

In my app, I try to import hawk

```
import * as hawk from '@hapi/hawk';
import { Credentials } from '@hapi/hawk/lib/client';
```

On serve, I got this error:

```
Error: ./src/app/hawk/auth.interceptor.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@hapi/hawk' in 'absence-io/src/app/hawk'
```

My tsconfig files:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}


/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["hapi__hawk"]
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your tsconfig file?

Comment: Yes, i have edit my question

Comment: Looks like to see nothing weird. Can you share your reproducible repo? So I can check for you

Comment: Sure and tanks. The repo is on github now: https://github.com/ThRintelen/absence.io

Comment: Looks like the typing `@types/hapi__hawk` which declares for the newer package `@hapi/hawk` instead.  So you need to install  hawk from `@hapi/hawk` but as you installed it, you would see some node apis are included to the webpack process then you would have to exclude them by specifying such as `{ browser:  { "fs": false, ... } }`. But there is another  error is a package need babel to support transpiling. You might need to configure webpack for that